# Excel Search on Multiple Workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

first of all, many thanks for your help. I have been looking around on the internet and this is the closest thing I could find to our issue(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iHTKk0MVQxA&t=218s , by the way, thanks to www.teachexcel.com). The problem I have got is that we have multiple spreadsheets, docs, zip files... where the information unfortunately because it comes from different clients, different formats and it has no consistency whatsoever. Even using spreadsheets of the same client, sometimes don't have the same field names....

I have no experience with vba, so I would be extremely grateful if you could help. Is there any way in which instead of looking on a range of fields(ie name, id), it could look everywhere in the spreadsheet to find the input search field that you are looking for, in all the spreadsheets within a folder? I am not even going to ask about docx, or zip, pdf files, as I understand that is proper crazy... but if unless we could pull out the data from all the spreadsheets within a folder, that would be amazing!

The code on the video works fantastic, but it is limited to the user input range:

```
Sub Data_Search(wbMaster As Workbook, wbSlave As Workbook)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim dashboard As Worksheet
Dim dataArray As Variant
Dim datatoShowArray As Variant

Set dashboard = wbMaster.Sheets("Dashboard")

dataColumnStart = 1
dataColumnEnd = 15
dataColumnWidth = dataColumnEnd - dataColumnStart ' Number of columns for the raw data (+1 not included because it makes lower calculations more confusing)
dataRowStart = 2
dashboardDataColumnStart = 2 ' Column for the data on the dashboard

searchValue = dashboard.Range("C4").Value
FieldValue = dashboard.Range("E4").Value

If (FieldValue = "ID") Then
    searchField = 1
ElseIf (FieldValue = "Name") Then
    searchField = 2
ElseIf (FieldValue = "Workbook") Then
    searchField = 3
End If

For Each ws In wbSlave.Worksheets

    If (ws.Name <> "Dashboard") Then


        'Example usage: dataArray(1,1) [row,column]
        'Simple version: ws.Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(2,2)).Value
        dataArray = ws.Range(ws.Cells(dataRowStart, dataColumnStart), ws.Cells(ws.Cells(Rows.Count, dataColumnStart).End(xlUp).Row, dataColumnEnd)).Value

        'Increase size of array that will hold the data to display to its max possible size for the current worksheet.
        ReDim datatoShowArray(1 To UBound(dataArray, 1), 1 To UBound(dataArray, 2))

        'Row increment for the final data array (datatoShowArray).
        j = 1

        'Loop through the rows in the data range.
        For i = 1 To UBound(dataArray, 1)

            'Check if the value in the row equals our search value
            If (dataArray(i, searchField) = searchValue) Then

                'MATCH FOUND! Now do something!

                'Loop through the columns in the data range so can get their values.
                For k = 1 To UBound(dataArray, 2)

                    'Add values to the array that will be used to put data into the Dashboard.
                    datatoShowArray(j, k) = dataArray(i, k)

                Next k

                'Increment the counter for the datatoShowArray
                j = j + 1

            End If

        Next i

        'Find next empty row in the dashboard.
        nextRow = dashboard.Cells(Rows.Count, dashboardDataColumnStart).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        'Put data into the dashboard.
        'Format = Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(2,2)).Value = datatoShowArray
        'dashboard.Range(Cells(nextRow, dashboardDataColumnStart), Cells(nextRow + UBound(datatoShowArray, 1) - 1, dashboardDataColumnStart + dataColumnWidth)).Value = datatoShowArray
        dashboard.Range(dashboard.Cells(nextRow, dashboardDataColumnStart), dashboard.Cells(nextRow + UBound(datatoShowArray, 1) - 1, dashboardDataColumnStart + dataColumnWidth)).Value = datatoShowArray

    End If

'Go to the next worksheet.
Next ws

'Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Turn it back on at the end of the macro!

End Sub
Sub Clear_Data()

'Dashboard sheet
Set dashboard = Sheets("Dashboard")

'Data table information
dashboardDataColumnStart = 2 ' Column for the data on the dashboard
dashboardDataRowStart = 11

dashboard.Range(dashboard.Cells(dashboardDataRowStart, dashboardDataColumnStart), dashboard.Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count)).Clear

End Sub
Sub Search_Separate_Workbooks()
    ' TeachExcel.com

Dim fileName As String
Dim wbMaster As Workbook
Dim wbSlave As Workbook


'Dont update the screen - makes it work faster
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Set the master workbook - one that will display the results.
Set wbMaster = ActiveWorkbook

'Clear Dashboard
Call Clear_Data

'Directory from which to get the workbook.
directoryToSearch = "C:\test\"

'Search Single Workbook
'fileName = Dir(directoryToSearch + "test1.xlsx")

'Search Entire Directory
fileName = Dir(directoryToSearch + "*xlsx*")

'Loop through all workbooks.
Do While Len(fileName) > 0

    ' Save a reference to, and open, the workbook to search through.
    Set wbSlave = Workbooks.Open(directoryToSearch + fileName)

    ' Open the method that searches the workbooks and tell them which workbook to search and where to place the data.
    Call Data_Search(wbMaster, wbSlave)

    ' Close the workbook that was searched through and don't save any changes to it, if any were made.
    wbSlave.Close SaveChanges:=False

    ' DON'T FORGET THIS!!! Otherwise, you enter a never ending loop!
    fileName = Dir

Loop

'Turn on screen updating again - makes Excel usable
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: @BigBen I am trying but because it is commented gives me error.. is there other way I could share the code? thanks

Comment: @GeertBellekens thanks Geert. Yes I am aware of that. I need the data to be searched in multiple files (excel, docx,..I guess ultimately only excel files) and output the information when finds whatever we are looking for, and put it on a list. Windows explorer will tell you in which files can be found, but will not put together a list with the information

Comment: Ok, but I think I would look into a solution that somehow uses a standard search solution to get we what I need and use the output of that search in my code to create the list you need. Why re-invent a search function. After all, *The best code is no code at all*

Comment: @GeertBellekens, thanks. you might be right that I am trying to reinvent the wheel, but as unfortunately I have no coding idea, I would not even be able to do what you suggested....